# Once he said... or when he said...?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

*Once he said "developed by a chiropractor," I took it with a few tablespoons of salt.* Can I substitute word *Once* for word *When*?

Comment: If you use ***when*** in such contexts, you might just be neutrally reporting the sequence in which events took place (which *could* in principle have happened in a different order). But using ***once*** implies some kind of "causal" link (i.e. - the implication is the second event wouldn't have happened at all unless and until the first had happened).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two in this context have effectively the same meaning. However, I think you mean "with a pinch of salt" or "with a grain of salt": https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+with+a+pinch+of+salt

Comment: I got marked down there - I don't know why. Within context they are equivalent; any nuance between the two is unnecessary nitpicking.

Comment: When people say a "few tablespoons of salt", or "a heaping teaspoon of salt", or "quite a bit of salt", etc, they are usually trying to intensify the idiom meaning, "not *sure* if it is believable", and turn it into "not believable at all".

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the context. "Once" can mean "As soon as" or "At the moment when", whereas "When" by itself does not have that "momentary" flavour.